# dynamic web page after i come back

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dynamic, history

I am a relatively new webpage designer. My current issue is that I have a webpage dynamically loading content and modifying the history. I am able to dynamically change the content as the web page shifts from page to page but when I leave the website and use history to come back to it, I keep getting 404 page not found. Is there anyway to remedy this situation?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
         $('#bodywrap').load('/common/index.php');

         $('ul#nav li a').click(function(e) {
             $("#loading").show();
             href = $(this).attr("href");
             loadContent(href);
             // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
             history.pushState('', '', href);
             e.preventDefault();
         });
         $(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
             $("#loading").show();
             console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
             loadContent(location.pathname);
         });
    });
    function loadContent(url){
        // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
        $('#bodywrap').load('/common/'+url+'.php');
        $("#loading").hide();
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am unaware of any other way to do this. If you could offer some insight I would love it :) @BitwiseCreative

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was overly assumptious and dramatic. @Baneet Grover

Comment: haha no worries, like i said im new to this and trying to understand how to use it :) @BitwiseCreative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hashes so the underlying web server doesn't try to find an actual document there. Remember, the web server router runs first. Also, you'll need to check for a hash on load in order to pull the correct content if reloaded from history, or if accessed directly. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('#bodywrap').load('common/index.php');
        // Handle page load
        loadHref();
        // handle link click
        $('ul#nav li a').click(function(e) {
            $("#loading").show();
            href = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
            loadContent(href);
            // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
            history.pushState('', '', $(this).attr("href"));
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        // Handle popstate
        $(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
            $("#loading").show();
            loadHref();
        });
    });
    function loadContent(url){
        // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
        $('#bodywrap').load('common/'+url+'.php');
        $("#loading").hide();
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
    }
    function loadHref() {
        var href;
        var loadHref = window.location.href;
        if (loadHref.indexOf('#') > -1) {
            href = loadHref.substr(loadHref.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
            loadContent(href);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that your links will need to be hashes:

```
<a href="#about">About</a>
```

Comment: This seems to be loading the same way. It solves the issue where I am not getting a 404 error but if i put in the link in this case localhost:8888/#about it gives me a blank page

Comment: correction: it seems to be working now but i have to refresh multiple times. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Yes, because the hash URL wasn't being handled in the `popstate` event. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the same functionality for my project http://forkphp.com ,
you can use this code with some changes.

```
$(document).on('click','.changepage',function () {

          // body...
          prev = window.location; 
          next = "<?php echo $this->appBase(); ?>"+url; // url to load
          var url = 'YOUR_URL';
          var target = $(this).attr('target'); // body in your case
        $.ajax(
            {
              url:"<?php echo $this->appBase(); ?>"+url,
              method:'POST',
              data:{terminal:1},
              dataType:'json',
              beforeSend:function(){
              //  $(target).disablify(); // show loader
              },
              success:function(data)
              {

              $(target).html(data.html);
               document.title = data.title;
              // $(target).enablify(); // hide loader
               window.history.pushState({"html":data.html,"pageTitle":"history"},"", "<?php echo $this->appBase(); ?>"+url);
              }
            });
      });
```

Comment: yes, you can. All you need to do is to replace the base url method in your code.